# VBScript Excel to CSV converter is very slow and Protected view slows it even more

Tags: excel, vbscript

I found a VBScript to convert Excel files to CSV files, and modified it to my needs. The files I'm dealing with are usually in protected view, so I have the following code:

```
format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.ProtectedViewWindows.Open(src_file)
If oExcel.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    oExcel.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.Worksheets(5).Activate

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oExcel.Quit
```

This script removes the protected view from the Excel files and saves the current selected worksheet as a csv file. If I run this the first time, it takes about 25-27 seconds to convert 4 protected view excel files into csv files. When I run it the second time, where the excel files are no longer in protected view, I get a similar result. I was curious to see what would happen if I removed the checking for Protected View, so I did the following:

```
format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.Worksheets(5).Activate

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, format

oExcel.AutomationSecurity = lSecurity

oBook.Close False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oExcel.Quit
```

Now I can't open protected excel files with this script, but if the excel files are unprotected it converts them much more quickly than the previous script. The same 4 excel files that are now not in protected view take an average 14 seconds to convert into csv files. I have ran this many times to make sure and I get the same result every time.

Why does checking for protected view cause the script to take much longer? Are there any ways to make it run faster? Also, are there any other alternatives to converting Excel files to CSV through command line? I also tried Powershell and it was even faster than VBScript! but I couldn't get it to work for protected view files. I should mention that I am running these scripts through QProcess in Qt 5.6. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one you are opening the file 2 times! One for `oExcel.ProtectedViewsWindow` and one for `oExcel.Workbooks`.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.ProtectedViewWindows.Open(src_file)
Dim oBook
If oExcel.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    Set oBook = oExcel.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
Else
    Set oBook = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
End If

oBook.Worksheets(5).Activate

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: You are a life saver. It works! Now it takes about 17 seconds to convert the 4 excel files, a great improvement. However, is it possible to make it even faster? In my GUI program I run this script an amount of times according to the number of excel files (in this case the script ran 4 times). Do you think it would be faster if instead I just run the script once and iterate over the excel files? That way I wouldn't have to create many Excel.Applications. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about VB. But I think this is possible, may be with the `Windows` property of `Excel.Application`.

Comment: No problem. I managed to figure it out and it did reduce the time by about 4 seconds.